# Golangのデバッグでwatch変数を設定できない

Tags: go, debugging

lldbを使って下記のコード内の`c`という変数をwatchしたいのですが、Errorが起きてうまくいきません。どうすればいいのでしょうか?

`go build -gcflags "-N -l" forprint.go`と実行した後にlldbに入り、watchすると
`invalid thread`というErrorが起きます。

OS: OS X 10.11.1
lldb: lldb-340.4.70
Go: 1.5.1

forprint.go

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    c := 1
    for c <= 100 {
        fmt.Println(c)
        c++ // cをwatchしたい
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらとは環境が異なりますので、回答になるのかどうかは不明です。

`invalid thread` と表示されるのは、プログラムがまだ実行されていない(実行コンテクストが存在しない)から、です。ですので、まずは breakpoint を main 関数などに設定してプログラムを実行する必要があります。

以下はこちらの環境で watchpoint を設定するまでの流れです。

```shell
$ go version
go version go1.4.2 gccgo (Ubuntu 5.1.1-4ubuntu12) 5.1.1 20150504 linux/386

$ go build -gcflags "-N -l" lldb-test.go

$ lldb --version
lldb version 3.7.0 ( revision )

$ lldb ./lldb-test

(lldb) breakpoint set -n main.main
(lldb) run
Process 7837 launched: './lldb-test' (i386)
Process 7837 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 7837, 0x080496b5 lldb-test`main.main + 26 at lldb-test.go:6, name = 'lldb-test', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x080496b5 lldb-test`main.main + 26 at lldb-test.go:6
   3    import "fmt"
   4
   5    func main() {
-> 6        c := 1
   7        for c <= 100 {
   8            fmt.Println(c)
   9            c++ // cをwatchしたい

(lldb) fr variable
(int) c = 134519177

(lldb) watchpoint set variable c
Watchpoint created: Watchpoint 1: addr = 0xb5fcffec size = 4 state = enabled type = w
    declare @ '/home/nemo/lldb-test.go:6'
    watchpoint spec = 'c'
    new value: 134519177
(lldb) watchpoint list
Number of supported hardware watchpoints: 4
Current watchpoints:
Watchpoint 1: addr = 0xb5fcffec size = 4 state = enabled type = w
    declare @ '/home/nemo/lldb-test.go:6'
    watchpoint spec = 'c'
    new value: 134519177

(lldb) cont
Process 7837 resuming
Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 134519177   <-- 1st
new value: 1
Process 7837 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 7837, 0x080496bc lldb-test`main.main + 33 at lldb-test.go:7, name = 'lldb-test', stop reason = watchpoint 1
    frame #0: 0x080496bc lldb-test`main.main + 33 at lldb-test.go:7
   4
   5    func main() {
   6        c := 1
-> 7        for c <= 100 {
   8            fmt.Println(c)
   9            c++ // cをwatchしたい
   10       }

(lldb) cont
Process 7837 resuming
Watchpoint 1 hit:
old value: 1   <-- 2nd
new value: 2
Process 7837 stopped
* thread #3: tid = 7893, 0x08049742 lldb-test`main.main + 167 at lldb-test.go:7, name = 'lldb-test', stop reason = watchpoint 1
    frame #0: 0x08049742 lldb-test`main.main + 167 at lldb-test.go:7
   4
   5    func main() {
   6        c := 1
-> 7        for c <= 100 {
   8            fmt.Println(c)
   9            c++ // cをwatchしたい
   10       }
```

**追記(2015/12/23)**

lldb のバージョンが 3.8 になっていましたので試してみました。

```
## 今回は amd64 CPU
$ uname -srm
Linux 4.2.0-22-generic x86_64

## golang 1.6 Beta 1 相当
$ go version
go version devel +97f854c Sat Dec 19 10:00:04 2015 +0000 linux/amd64

$ lldb --version
lldb version 3.8.0 ( revision )
```

この環境で上記と同じ手順でデバッグを行ったところ、結果は同じで問題はありませんでした。

Comment: 実行すると`breakpoint set -n main.main`のところで`Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.`というエラーが発生してしまいます。

Comment: @KiYugadgeter lldb がまだ golang 1.5 系に対応していない様で、現状では 1.4 系だけでしか使えない様です。

Comment: 2016/3/22 os xのcommand line toolsのupdateでbuiltinのlldbでもdebugできるようになったようです